# Best way to handle permission with git

Tags: git, file-permissions, user-permissions

So while playing around with my server i tried to set up git for my `/var/www` folder. It works fine. I can push and pull the data from my local machine to/from the server without any problems. What i am wondering now is: Is there a way to define the default onwership and group of new added files by git?

My Setup on the server is like this: I have 3 users, 2 are real persons with sudo ALL permissions and one is the "git" user account which is used for all the git operations. All three users are inside the www-data group. If i create a new file locally and commit it to my server the permission looks like this:

```
-rwx-r-sr-x git:www-data
```

I am not really an expert when it comes to file permissions, but i can imagine that this kind of ownership and "restricted" rights for the www-data group can cause problems when i add php files, can it? Is this the way to go? Are there better ways of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider adding a post-receive hook to change the permissions.  Changing ownership must be done as root and is in general not a good plan, especially not from a hook.  (This is a feature--*not* a limitation--of Unix... Git runs as its own user, so files it creates will be accessible to it only.)

Comment: Well i found out that with those rights it works perfectly fine up to a certain point where it wouldn't be too hard to just change it with root. If i encounter any problems and / or find a solution i will let you know. The suggestion with a post-receive hook also already crossed my mind.